# Snackbar shows empty message before clearing

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm showing a Material-UI snackbar, using a message from Redux:

```js
const MySnackBar = () => {
  const message = useSelector(({ data }: RootState) => data.message)
  
  return (
    <Snackbar open={ !!message }>
      <Alert variant={ 'filled' }>{ message }</Alert>
    </Snackbar>
  )
}
```

I have redux actions that write the message to the store, and then clear the message (`message = ''`) after a timeout.

```js
export const showMessage = (dispatch: any, message: string) => {
  dispatch(setMessage(message))
  setTimeout(() => dispatch(clearMessage()), 3000)
}
```

This works, except that before the snackbar actually disappears, it shows with the blank message.

I guess this is because of how transition animations work, where it the snackbar starts to animate out once `open` is set to false.

What's the best way to implement the snackbar so that it hides "correctly"?

I imagine one solution would be having a boolean `showSnackbar` entry in my store, and not clearing the message. This seems slightly clunky, requiring two pieces of information rather than one, and I don't like the smell of leaving the message in the store when it's not being shown.

But I imagine that maybe that's still the best way despite those "shortcomings."

What do people like to do for this?